# Can't create a file in Plan 9 acme

Tags: editor, plan-9

I'm running Plan 9 OS in VirtualBox. The host OS is Fedora 14.

When I run `acme hello.c` there's an error saying:

```
can't open hello.c:'hello.c' file does not exist
```

I'm following this guide [newbie-guide](http://www.quanstro.net/newbie-guide.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

To create a new file in Acme:

1. Click with the middle mouse button on the `New` command at the top of any column.
2. Create a tag in the new window, i.e. just write the filename at the top left of the new window.
3. Click with the middle mouse button on the `Put` command at the top of the new window.

or

1. Write `touch hello.c` somewhere.
2. Mark `touch hello.c` using the middle mouse button, i.e. move the mouse pointer just before the phrase, press and hold the middle mouse button, move the mouse to the end of the phrase, release the button.
3. Click hello.c with the right mouse button.

To open an existing file in Acme:

1. Write the filename anywhere and click it with the right mouse button.

Acme is really intuitive once you grasp a few basic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you should be able to create the file and then edit it:

```
term% touch hello.c
term% acme hello.c
```

which works fine on my system.